# output for the following c# snippet

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        string s = p.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The output I am receiving is 27
Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because the string representation of Program class, basically it's full name (namespace and class name) as string has this number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of the `ToString` method is to return the name of the type, so your string `s` contains the full type name of the `Program` class, i.e. something like `"MySecondTestProgram.Program"`, and that is what you are getting the length of.